# AngularJS ng-options use filter and orderBy components together for select dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dropdown, ng-options

I have dropdown in angularJS using ng-options. I need to use filter: and  orderBy: component together for the ng-options
My filter for the select is working fine, however the OrderBy: component does not seem to be working.

Below is my code implementation of what I have tried:

```
<label class="control-label">My Dropdown 123</label>
<input type="search" ng-model="searchFilter.Name" class="" placeholder="Search"></input>
<select class="form-control" 
        ng-options="l as (l.ID ? (l.ID  + ' ' + '-' + ' '): '' ) + l.Name  + ' ' +'('+ l.ID + ') ' for l in vm.values | orderBy: l.Name | filter: searchFilter track by l.ID "
        data-ng-model="vm.values"
        ng-disabled="vm.isReadOnly">        
    <option value="">All</option>
</select>
```

Please guide and advice as how I can make the orderBy and filter work together for ng-options in AngularJS with HTML.

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by using :

```
| orderBy: 'l.Name'
```

The orderBy parameter has to be in single quotes '' for the orderBy: component to work

Hope it is helpful for others :)